# Is this grammatically correct? "I have been the completion of the modifications on the site."

Tags: passive-voice, progressive-aspect

Is the following sentence correct ?

> I have been the completion of the modifications on the site.

Comment: Hi M.abo sal, proofreading is not encouraged here on ELL. Just to help out here, the sentence is incorrect. Try "I have completed the modifications on the site". or "The modifications on the site has been completed by me".

Comment: If the process is ongoing, it can be: "I have been completing the modifications ..."

Answer (score 1):

> I have been the completion of the modifications on the site.

The sentence isn't correct grammatically.  I think the OP wants to form this sentence in the passive. The correct sentence is as follows:

> The modifications have been completed by me on the site.